# Print worksheets depending on checkbox. Slower than before

Tags: vba, excel

I have an userform that has check boxes where user can decide which worksheets to print.

Code in userform:

```
Sub PrintOK_Click()

PrintSelection = Summary.value + _
CCSummary.value + _
DivSalaries.value + _
CCSalaries.value + _
PrintAll.value _

' Displays warning box if no report is selected
If PrintSelection = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Report(s) selected. Please select Report(s) to print.", 0 + vbExclamation, "Incomplete Request"
End If

' Check to see which worksheets have been selected and
' Run print modules for selected worksheets
    If Summary.value = -1 Then
        Call setup("Summary")
    End If

    If CCSummary.value = -1 Then
        Call setup("Monthly CC Sum")
    End If

    If DivSalaries.value = -1 Then
        Call setup("Div Sal Sum")
    End If

    If CCSalaries.value = -1 Then
        Call setup("CC Sal Sum")
    End If

    If PrintAll.value = -1 Then
        Call setup("PrintAll")
    End If

' Close Form box
End
End Sub
```

Userform selection is passed into the following. Takes the worksheet(s) selected and stores into array.

```
Sub setup(Optional tabs As String)
'store sheets into array

Dim arr() As Variant

'called from printer icon on activesheet
If tabs = "" Then
    arr = Array(ActiveSheet.Name)

'called via checkbox from print menu
ElseIf tabs = "PrintAll" Then
    arr = Array("Summary", "Monthly CC Sum", "Div Sal Sum", "CC Sal Sum")
Else
    arr = Array(tabs)
End If

Call goPrint(arr)

End Sub
```

Which then passes the array to another sub to do the printing

```
Sub goPrint(tabArr As Variant)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim area As String
Dim title As String

'loop through array to print each sheet
For i = 0 To UBound(tabArr)

    Set ws = Worksheets(tabArr(i))

    With ws

        If .Name = "Summary" Then
            area = "PRNSUMMARY"
            title = "$1:$9"
        ElseIf .Name = "Monthly CC Sum" Then
            area = "PRNMONTHLYCCSUM"
            title = "$2:$16"
        ElseIf .Name = "Div Sal Sum" Then
            area = "PRNDIVSALSUM"
            title = ""
        ElseIf .Name = "CC Sal Sum" Then
            area = "PRNCCSALSUM"
            title = "$2:$16"
        End If

        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = area
            .PrintTitleRows = title
            .PrintTitleColumns = ""
            .LeftHeader = ""
            .CenterHeader = ""
            .RightHeader = ""
            .LeftFooter = Year(Now()) & " Budget:   &F"
            .CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
            .RightFooter = "&D:   &T"
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .PrintHeadings = False
            .PrintGridlines = False
            .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
            '.PrintQuality = 600
            .CenterHorizontally = False
            .CenterVertically = False
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Draft = False
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
            .Order = xlDownThenOver
            .BlackAndWhite = False
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
        End With

        'Debug.Print tabArr(i)
        'Debug.Print area
        .PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True

    End With

Next

End Sub
```

There's a delay of maybe two seconds after pressing OK before the printer starts to print. The previous (much longer) code had no discernible delay. How to improve speed?

(Previous code had a different sub for each worksheet thus repeating the `pagesetup` code block multiple times.)

Comment: Welcome to CR! What are `Summary` and `CCSummary` in the userform code? I'd love to see the entire procedure there... Also, are `setup` and `goPrint` written in separate modules?

Comment: Those are names assigned to the checkboxes. Please see updated code in its entirety.  `setup` and `goprint` are in the same module. Obviously, code for `printok_click` is inside the userform (separate module).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *(Previous code had a different sub for each worksheet thus repeating the pagesetup code block multiple times.)*

Was the *previous code* also working directly with `Worksheet` objects by any chance?

You're working with an array of strings / sheet names...

> ```
> 'called from printer icon on activesheet
> If tabs = "" Then
>     arr = Array(ActiveSheet.Name)
>
> 'called via checkbox from print menu
> ElseIf tabs = "PrintAll" Then
>     arr = Array("Summary", "Monthly CC Sum", "Div Sal Sum", "CC Sal Sum")
> Else
>     arr = Array(tabs)
> End If
> ```

...*and then* creating worksheet objects as you iterate the array:

> ```
> 'loop through array to print each sheet
> For i = 0 To UBound(tabArr)
>
>     Set ws = Worksheets(tabArr(i))
> ```

Why not work with an array of `Worksheet` objects instead, and simply iterate that array?

```
If tabs = vbNullString then
    arr = Array(ActiveSheet)
ElseIf tabs = "PrintAll" then
    arr = Array(SummarySheet, MonthlySummary, DivSalSumSheet, CCSalSumSheet)
Else
    sheetNames = Split(tabs, ",")
    arrLength = UBound(sheetNames)
    ReDim arr(0 To arrLength)
    For i = 0 To arrLength
        arr(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNames(i))
    Next
End If
```

That's still brittle though - ideally you'd have the worksheet *references* themselves handy, ready to be passed to that `goPrint` method.

The `goPrint` method could then simply iterate the object array with a simple `For Each`:

```
For Each ws In tabArr
```

---

This code isn't ideal either; your previous code was also a little faster because it didn't need to check this condition:

> ```
>     If .Name = "Summary" Then
>         area = "PRNSUMMARY"
>         title = "$1:$9"
>     ElseIf .Name = "Monthly CC Sum" Then
>         area = "PRNMONTHLYCCSUM"
>         title = "$2:$16"
>     ElseIf .Name = "Div Sal Sum" Then
>         area = "PRNDIVSALSUM"
>         title = ""
>     ElseIf .Name = "CC Sal Sum" Then
>         area = "PRNCCSALSUM"
>         title = "$2:$16"
>     End If
> ```

If the sheet name is `CC Sal Sum` then you accessed and compared the worksheet's name 4 times already. And if it's something else, ...you get whatever you get.

This would be a nice *case* for a `Select Case` statement:

```
Select Case .Name
    Case "Summary"
        '...
    Case "Monthly CC Sum"
        '...
    Case "Div Sal Sum"
        '...
    Case "CC Sal Sum"
        '...
    Case Else
        'handle unexpected input?
 End Select
```

At runtime, a `Select Case` block pretty much amounts to a conditional `GoTo` jump, which means no matter how many cases you have, you'll only ever evaluate the condition **once**.

---

A note about this:

> ```
> ' Close Form box
> End
> ```

That's the big red "NUKE 'EM ALL" button. Sure, `End` will *close the form box*. But it will also *end* the macro. It's very very very rare that you actually need to do this.

Compare to:

```
'Close form box
Me.Hide
```

Is that comment even needed then?

---

Structurally, the main issue I'm seeing is that the code is relying on side-effects: the form calls `setup`, and then closes. What's `setup` doing then? Shouldn't it *set things up* for printing?

Oh, it does... but it's also calling `goPrint` - which is a side-effect that makes it much harder to write a test for the method and see if it works as intended. Everything is *coupled*, and the UI is running the show.

What if you flipped things around instead, and controlled things *from the outside*?

```
Sub PromptAndPrint()

    Dim model As New SelectionModel
    model.Selection = "PrintAll"

    Dim view As New SelectionForm
    Set view.ViewModel = model
    view.Show vbModal

    If view.IsCancelled Then Exit Sub

    ConfigurePageSetup model.SelectedWorksheets
    PrintSheets model.SelectedWorksheets

End Sub
```

That's right: the UI becomes nothing more than a *presentation* tool; the execution flow is controlled by the macro, not by the UI, and then you have some `SelectionModel` class responsible for encapsulating the data you want to pass around, and abstract away the `sheet names -> worksheet objects` transformation; you can test `ConfigurePageSetup` without wasting a sheet of paper, and you can test the whole `SelectionModel` functionality without even showing the UI, without configuring page setup *and* without wasting a sheet of paper: VBA is much more object-oriented than people generally want to admit.

---

Nitpicks:

- Indentation isn't always consistent. Consider using VBE add-ins like the latest [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com) or [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com), which offer automatic indentation (disclaimer: I'm heavily involved in Rubberduck).
- Member names don't follow common naming conventions. Use `PascalCase`, not `camelCase`, for public members; that's consistent with every single type library and object model available to VBA.

Also:

- Consider using explicit access modifiers. Procedures are implicitly `Public` by default.
- Consider using explicit parameter modifiers. Parameters are passed `ByRef` unless specified otherwise.
- Consider extracting the margins to a user-defined type, or at least a few constants.
- Consider removing the `Call` keyword, which is obsolete/useless (and then, remove the parentheses).
- Consider using the zero-footprint `vbNullString` built-in constant, instead of an empty string literal that eats up a whole 2 bytes for no reason.

Comment: lol CR is on a whole different level XD So uh, I have never made a class so probably won't go there but array of worksheets...yea.... ^_^;

Comment: Indeed, CR is a completely different ball game! Classes are your friends, don't be scared!

Comment: @findwindow If you think classes are a bit beyond you. A) they're not. trust me. B) Just start with [Custom Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262341%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40629/discussion-on-answer-by-mats-mug-print-worksheets-depending-on-checkbox-slower).